# What are the security concerns from failing to unpin memory?

Tags: denial-of-service, memory, cve

I am trying to understand the implication of [CVE-2023-40791](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-40791). The CVE reads:

> "Linux kernel before 6.4.12 fails to unpin pages in certain situations".

[NetApp](https://security.netapp.com/advisory/ntap-20231110-0009/) says this could lead to modification of data or denial of service. Is that really realistic?

Comment: The links in the CVE explain how a crash was possible (DoS). So, that's confirmed.

Comment: Note that the CVE is rated "Medium" in NVD, however NetApp rates it as "Critical" and they score it very differently. So it might be an issue that is unique to their environment.

Comment: *"Is that really realistic?"* - what makes you believe that NetApp exaggerates on the impact of the vulnerability? It's more common that vendors downplay issues whenever possible, since it affects their reputation. So if NetApp believes that the issue has this impact on their platform then it probably has.

Comment: @schroeder The links in the CVE talk about warnings and show a call trace. Does that really showcase the possibility of DoS?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That is true. In general though, what kind of security problems would a "failure to unpin memory pages" cause and how?

Comment: Yes, the one where the problem is initially reported does...

Comment: @Munazh: *"In general though, what kind of security problems would a "failure to unpin memory pages" cause and how?"* - There is no generic class of security problems caused by a generic failure to unpin. It boils down that one parts of the system has some expectations how things work, while another part of the system does it differently than expected. Such discrepancy can result in a  variety of results, from crashing, data corruption, data leakage, ... . It really depends on the specific cases. Same with other generic kinds of bugs, like out of bound write etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ok makes sense. Thanks!